# How to reference a JVM variable in eclipse.ini

Tags: eclipse, jvm-arguments

I would like to specify a custom value for `java.io.tmpdir` in `eclipse.ini` file. Specifically, I need to have a username as part of the path.

I see the following entry in my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
```

But when I try to use similar lines for my purpose:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse_@user.name
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse_{@user.name}
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse_@{user.name}
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/@user.name
```

I end up with the following directories (literally):

```
/tmp/eclipse_@user.name
/tmp/eclipse_{@user.name}
/tmp/eclipse_@{user.name}
/tmp/@user.name
```

How could I specify my `-D` option so that `@user.name` is substituted with the actual username (e.g., `john_doe`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse.ini does not support variable substitution.

The `@user.home` and `@user.dir` substitution is done by the Equinox location code and consequently is only supported for the Equinox location values which are:

```
osgi.install.area
osgi.configuration.area
osgi.configuration.area.default
osgi.instance.area
osgi.instance.area.default
osgi.user.area
osgi.user.area.default
```

The code that does this is `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.location.EquinoxLocations`